# PHP HTTP client not able to resolve web page

Tags: php, http, guzzle6

I am trying to use a Http client to store the HTML from a web page. The following code snippet shows how I have configured the Http client, it uses php-http/guzzle6-adapter.
I know from my tests that the client works properly when pointed at other webpages.

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client as GuzzleAdapter;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$config = [
    'verify' => false,
    'timeout' => 2
];
$adapter = GuzzleAdapter::createWithConfig($config);

$request = new Request('GET', 'https://workingwithchildren.wa.gov.au/');

// Returns a Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface
$response = $adapter->sendRequest($request);

echo $response->getBody();

?>
```

However page I am trying to resolve https://workingwithchildren.wa.gov.au/ returns the following error, no matter what I do.

> The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.
>
> Your support ID is: 9283834035315018727

I pointed my browser at the website and used Chrome Developer Tools to examine the Request/Response data being exchanged.  The screenshot below shows the Response data my browser received.

[image: Screenshot]

I noticed that the site is setting cookies that seem to relate to security and CPFS and I would imagine these cookies are what are stopping my client from resolving the web page successfully. But I don't know how to fix this. I'd imagine this is a problem others have faced before. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Set a `User-Agent` as part of your guzzle config perhapps?

Comment: Thank you! Adding User-Agent data solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone experiencing a similar problem the solution I found was to, as the commenter Scuzzy suggested, add User-Agent data to my guzzle config.